# "ERROR while getting interface flags: no such device"

Tags: aircrack-ng

The command

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

gives as output

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.  
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after  
a short period of time you may want to kill (some of) them!
PID    Name
3258   wpa_supplicant
4175   NetworkManager
4180   dhclient
4190   avahi-daemon
4191   avahi-daemon 
Process with PID 4180 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0

Interface       Chipset       Driver  

wlan0           Unknown       wl - (phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: Onjuist apparaat  

                              (monitor mode emabled on mon0)
```

and then I type

```
ifconfig mon0 down
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR while getting interface flags: no such device
```

The error will probably start at `airmon-ng start wlan0`.

Comment: how did u actually solved this , can you post some details

Answer (score 4):

To quote from the [`aircrack-ng` site](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng#error_add_ifacepermission_denied):

> This means you have an old version of airmon-ng installed. Upgrade to at least v1.0-rc1.

They add chipset information/support in their newer releases, as well as incorporate patches.

To upgrade to the latest version of `aircrack-ng`, please follow the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/322468/52726).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for this error I came through so far.

1. Device is in use: Kill all processes mentioned which could cause trouble, e.g.

   `kill -9 3258` (kills your `wpa_supplicant`)
2. Update to latest `aircrack-ng` version: The [documentation](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng#error_add_ifacepermission_denied) suggests to update to the latest version from svn.

If this does not help, you should provide more information/details on the issue.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with the name of the interface

So, type `airmon-ng` to start your wireless interface in monitoring mode

Then type `airmon-ng check kill` to kill all the interfering processes

Now type

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

instead of typing

```
airodump-ng mon0
```

I hope this will work, if not please comment