# aircrack-ng : airmon-ng stop working after updating to 15.04 ( ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy )

Tags: networking, wireless, aircrack-ng

my aircrack-ng suite was working correctly until i updated to 15.04
i unsintal evrything and intsaled again form repositories to discard weird stuff and the problem is stil there:

```
 sudo airmon-ng 


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Atheros AR9565  ath9k - [phy0]

    kcdtv@profezorapplestruff:~$ sudo airmon-ng start wlan0


    Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
    If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
    a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

    PID Name
    595 avahi-daemon
    599 NetworkManager
    678 avahi-daemon
    749 wpa_supplicant
    795 dhclient


    Interface   Chipset     Driver

    wlan0       Atheros AR9565  ath9k - [phy0]SIOCSIFFLAGS: Le nom n'est pas unique sur le réseau

                    (monitor mode enabled on mon0)

    kcdtv@profezorapplestruff:~$ sudo airodump-ng mon0
    ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: Name not unique on network
```

I tryed to habilitate and deshabilitate network manger etc...

the only walk around i found is to bring down the interface and activate mode monitor with iwconfig 
Which does not satisfy me.
if i install aircrack-ng svn version i get the same fail but a more details in the shell:

```
    kcdtv@profezorapplestruff:~$ sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon
[sudo] password for kcdtv: 
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0mon <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

My host file look like that

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   profezorapplestruff

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and efectivly the device is til in managed mode:

```
/sbin/iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlan0mon
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x2
        addr 4c:bb:58:0f:ba:aa
        type managed
```

Does anyone have a clue? thank you

edit **solved with this trick!** : [Edit NewtorkManager.conf to prevent conflicts with airmon-ng (no check kill)](https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php/topic,1082.msg3303.html#msg3303)

Comment: Don't add "solved" into the title ;)

Comment: Sorry for that... That what we do in other forums... You should consider it;  it is not a bad system  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a nice trick to have airmon-ng working as it is supposed to; without any need to "check kill" or turn off completely network manager.
By the way It is network manager that is the cause of the problem since the version **0.9.8.10**.

*1*. Open your network manager configuration file as root in order to edit it

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

*2*. Add the following lines to prevent network manager from interfering  with airmon-ng

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0mon;interface-name:wlan1mon;interface-name:wlan2mon;interface-name:wlan3mon;interface-name:wlan4mon;interface-name:wlan5mon;interface-name:wlan6mon;interface-name:wlan7mon;interface-name:wlan8mon;interface-name:wlan9mon;interface-name:wlan10mon;interface-name:wlan11mon;interface-name:wlan12mon    #  avoid conflicts with airmon-ng
```

*The wlanXmon interfaces are just for monitor mode... So there is no problems if network manager can't manage them : It shouldn't!

  You can add as many interfaces as you want, 12 should be enough unless you are a addicted to buy wireless USB. Use the separator **;** between every interfaces.*

*3*. Saves the changes. Effects are immediate: you can now use mode monitor on one interface while you are connected to the Internet through network manager with another interface.

Solution previously published in aircrack-ng forum >
[Edit NewtorkManager.conf to prevent conflicts with airmon-ng (no check kill)](https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php/topic,1082.msg3303.html#msg3303)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about airmon-ng script and try this:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Now you can use airodump-ng with your interface in monitor mode:

```
sudo airodump-ng wlan0
```

Hope it helps. It worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
When I say in my post " (...) the only walk around i found is to bring down the interface and activate mode monitor with iwconfig Which does not satisfy me. "
I was exactly referring to the solution you gently gave :) 
For sure it works but I would like to get the airmon-ng working with a unique and 100% mode monitor interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the interface down.

Just follow these steps:

```
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start <interface>
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

[More infos](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng)

Comment: Thanks for answering    I don't want to "check kill" with airmon-ng to still have one of my interface connected to the internet. And also to have network manager enabled. It was working like a charm untill 15.04 without any need to "check kill"... problem is coming from newest network manager. cheers